# imprimir este json?

Tags: php

como puedo acceder a los elementos de este json?

```
string(305) "{"puesto":"181","sexo":"Hombre","edad":"28","experienciaPuesto":"1","diasTrabajados":"Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes","id":"6","idPromocion":"61,64,69,4","habilidades":"1,3,2","paquetesLenguajes":"Excel,Power point,Word","conocimientosEspecificos":"1,2","sueldo":"600.00","ultimoGradoEstudios":"6"}"
```

quize hacerlo de esta manera pero no me sale

```
echo $solicitudEmpleo['puesto'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes es una cadena de texto, no un objeto.

Primero tienes que convertir ese texto JSON a un objeto JSON.

```
$obj = json_decode($solicitudEmpleo,true);
echo $obj["puesto"];
```

El `true` es para poder manejarlo como "arreglo".

Comment: gracias no me di cuenta que era un string

Answer (score 0):

Tenés que decodear el json con [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), quedando así:

```
<?php
  $json = $solicitudEmpleo;

  var_dump(json_decode($json));
  var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

  $solicitudEmpleoArray = json_decode($solicitudEmpleo);
  // esto imprime "181"
  var_dump($solicitudEmpleoArray['puesto']);

?>
```

El primero lo imprime en un `object` y el segundo en un `array` indexado.